# Tweening a Kineticjs Shape

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I have a custom shape created in Kineticjs and I need the shape to tween like a line.  How would I go about doing this?  I've tried creating a Kinetic Tween but that doesn't seem to work correctly.

```
var grnStripe = new Image();
grnStripe.onload = start;
grnStripe.src = 'images/GreenStripe-01.png';
function start(){
grnLine = new Kinetic.Shape({
    sceneFunc: function (context) {
        var ctx = this.getContext()._context;
        var pattern = context.createPattern(grnStripe, 'repeat');
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(379.5, 270);
        ctx.lineTo(379.5, 270);
        ctx.strokeStyle = pattern;
        ctx.lineWidth = 2.5;
        ctx.stroke();
    }
});
line_layer.add(grnLine);
line_layer.draw();
}
```

I want the shape(line) to tween to a height of 310.  Again, I've tried to create a Kinetic Tween but it's not seeming to work.

[image: Mock of what I need]

Comment: can you provide image what you want?

Comment: I'm not allowed to provide the actual images I'm using.  I'll give you the placeholder image like in the last question you answered for me.

`'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg'`

Comment: my question is create a mock in mspaint what you want?

Comment: Ok, I added an example

Comment: still not clear to me

Comment: I want a green striped background as the stroke.  I'm just asking how it could be done, any image can be used as the stroke pattern, that's not what I'm concerned about, can replace the image on my end once I see how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

*Yes, you can Kinetic.Tween a Kinetic.Shape--even a shape with a pattern stroke.*

**[ A general answer about tweening a Kinetic.Shape ]**

The key to tweening a Kinetic.Shape is having `sceneFunc` change using a Kinetic.Shape property.

For example, this sceneFunc will draw a rectange based on that Kinetic.Shape's x & y properties.

```
sceneFunc: function(context) {
  var x=this.x();
  var y=this.y();
  context.fillRect(x,y,20,20);
},
```

Then you can use a Kinetic.Tween to change the Kinetic.Shapes' x/y which in turn will animate the rect.

For example this tween will animate a Kinetic.Shape called myShape from its current x/y to and x/y of [100,100].

```
tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
    node: myShape, 
    duration: 1,
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
  });
```

**[ A specific answer based on one of your previous questions about pattern-stroked lines ]**

The Kinetic.Shape context does not allow you to draw a pattern-stroked line.

As a workaround you can fetch the actual html context which does allow pattern-stroked lines.

*A "ghosting problem" when tweening:*

However, when you want to tween this pattern-filled line you have a "ghosting" problem because Kinetic actually uses 2 canvases for every layer and your pattern-filled line is incorrectly positioned on that second hit-canvas (a "ghost").  This is to be expected because Kinetic cannot be expected to know what you've drawn on your actual html context.

You can fix this ghosting problem by defining hitFunc in your custom Kinetic.Shape.  That allows Kinetic to correctly position your pattern-filled line on its second hit-canvas.  The ghosting is gone.

Here is a Fiddle demonstrating the workaround for your pattern-filled line:

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/GpSbd/